# What is the variance associated to the average gate fidelity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, estimation

Let $U$ be a unitary and $\mathcal E$ a map on a space of dimension $D$, and say we want to assess how "close" $U$ is to $\mathcal E$.

A standard way to do this is using the average fidelity $\overline{F}(\mathcal E, U)$, defined as
$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal E, U)\equiv\int d\psi
\langle\psi\rvert U^\dagger \mathcal E(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|) U|\psi\rangle.\tag1
$$
It is a standard result (see e.g. [quant-ph/0205035](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035)) that **(1)** can be computed as
$$
\overline{F}(\mathcal E, U) =
\frac{1}{D+1}\left[
1 + \frac{1}{D}
\langle i|U^\dagger \mathcal E(|i\rangle\langle j|)U|j\rangle
\right].
\tag2
$$

In the special case of $\mathcal E$ also being a unitary evolution (that is, $\mathcal E(\rho)=V\rho V^\dagger$ for some unitary $V$), the formula simplifies to
$$
\overline{F}(V, U) =
\frac{1}{D+1}\left[
1 + \frac{1}{D}
\lvert\operatorname{tr}(U^\dagger V)\rvert^2
\right].
\tag3
$$
These expressions are very useful as they allow to compute the average fidelity without actually computing an average over the states.

I wasn't however able to find discussed the matter of what the variance of this quantity actually is.
In other words, if I were to try to estimate **(1)** using a sample size of $N$ states, how likely am I to get a value close enough to the true average given by **(2)**?

To more clearly understand the question, here is a plot of the average fidelity between two unitary gates, estimated with various sample sizes and compared with the true value given by **(3)**:

[image]

I want to know how big do I need to choose the sample size in order to have a good enough estimate with a good enough confidence.

Is there any closed expression for this variance? Is there anything known about it (will it depend on $U$ and $\mathcal E$, how does it scale with system dimension, etc.)?

Comment: a few related papers are [Pederson et al. 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4843) and [Magesan et al. 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1315)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware, there is no simple expression for the variance of the average fidelity. However, the [sample variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html) can be computed easily. Suppose you prepared Haar random states and collected the data $\{f_i\}$ then the sample variance is
$$s_{N-1}^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_i (f_i - \bar{f})^2$$
where
$$\bar{f} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i f_i.$$

It is straightforward to determine how many samples you *need*. Alternatively, you could try bootstrapping or using Bayesian inference.

I should mention one more fact.
$$\text{Var}(\bar{F}) \leq O(\frac{1}{N})$$
where D is the dimension of your Hilbert space. This means that if your Hilbert space is large one random state is enough to determine the average fidelity with high probability!

Comment: thanks. Can you provide a reference for the bound on the variance of the average fidelity?

Comment: Page 84 of https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/6832/Magesan_Easwar.pdf. There are quite a few other results about the gate fidelity in there you may find useful.